# Passing PHP Result to JS via jQuery .get

Tags: php, jquery

I have several instances where a form is brought into the page in an overlay via ajax. On these forms I have a "math validation" question (I know not the most secure). I am using the following to generate the problem:

```
<?php
    $randomNum = rand(0,9);
    $randomNum2 = rand(0,9);
    $randomNumTotal = $randomNum + $randomNum2;
?>
```

the random number is displayed in a text box like so:

```
<input type="text" name="someName" value="<?= $randomNum ?> + <?= $randomNum2 ?>" readonly>
```

and validated:

```
...
SomeName: {
    required: true,
    equal: <?php echo $randomNumTotal; ?>   
 }
    ...
```

This works fine when the form is on the page, hidden and then displayed with a .click function. I would like to store the files remotely and display them via AJAX. No problem doing that, the problem is when I do this, the numbers generated don't match the value. I've tried putting the PHP $randomeNumTotal function on both the form itself that is brought in via AJAX and on the parent page. Neither works.

**So my question is this:** Can I store the PHP function in a remote file "random.php", then pass the value to it via .get? If so, how do I make "SomeName" value equal the value from the file?

```
<script>
  $.get( 'random.php', function ( data ) {
    $("SomeName").val('random.php')?//I know this isn't right
 });
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.get( 'random.php', function ( data ) {
    $("SomeName").val(data);
});
```

Should work. Alternatively, you could use jQuery's [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) if you wanted to load the content in as the HTML of any element.

Comment: Several stupid questions to follow....So I have the file "random.php" how do I include this in my parent page or the form page that is brought in? via PHP include? Then I click the button to open the form...which somehow has the box populated with the random numbers, and in the validation file I use the above to get the correct sum?

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design An XHR initiated by JavaScript will load that page in. You do not need to include it on the server side.

Comment: I knew that. Told you it was a stupid question. Thx for the help Alex. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design Glad it helped. jQuery's abstractions make things like this pretty trivial :)

Comment: @alex - when I use the above it doesn't return anything. The response is blank in firebug....

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design Is your `random.php` echoing anything when you access it with your browser?